# STM32 Hal Driver crashes on init

Tags: stm32, fault, hal

I have STM32F030C8T.
Using CubeMX to generate **basic** init code including:

```
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/


/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();

  /* Initialize interrupts */
  MX_NVIC_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
```

ADC, TIM6, USART have basic IRQ handlers.
Builds ok, but when debug starts - it goes to the hard fault or indefinite region... Works fine only if TIM6_init and USART_init are commented.
What can be wrong? In which way i need to look?

Comment: When program crashes? Does it crash inside `TIM6_init()` function?

Comment: It crashes if there is combination of init TIM6, USART1 and SPI2. When deleting some it comes ok. It crashes at the start. Debug session goes directly to nowhere or Hard Fault Handler.
Solved by moving from Atolic to Keil. I think it some glitch in GCC compiler or atollic itself.